# Passing propertyName, Condition Operator and Value to Function as a Linq query C#

Tags: c#, linq, parameter-passing, func

I am working with c# and i want to pass the properties of an object to a function in the form of a link query. The property, operator and value compared in the condition should be available to the function.

For Instance

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       MyMethod(p => p.Age != 23);
    }

    private static void MyMethod( Func<Model,object> parameters)
    {
        //How Do I get the ff
        //PropertyName : "Age"
        //Opertator : "!="
        //Value : 23           
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [Searchable]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Searchable]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Searchable]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What I actually would like to do is call the function like this `MyMethod(p => (p.Age != 23 , p.Name == "Titan"))`. And then access the parameterName, operator and value for each of the queries. I intend to hook Mymethod to a `Model` (preferably exposing only the properties with searchable attribute). The idea here is to use the propertyname, operator and value to build an sql where clause. this is the idea i have to achieve this. Unless there is a better way?

I do not know how else to formulate this question. But i hope its clear enough

Comment: Use a [predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Comment: I assume you don't use some ORM like Entity Framework and want to build raw sql queries?

Comment: No I do not use an ORM. I am working on a legacy system build on raw sql.  I want call `MyMethod` and pass a number of conditional expressions. only that this time i want to have access to the lhs, operator and rhs of each conditional expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to analyze the expression you pass to function you have to use `Expression` class, not just `Func<Model, object>`. Here is a sketch of how you can analyze expression. Obviously it's just for demonstration purposes and you should adjust it to your scenario (also take a look at `ExpressionVisitor` class and how it can be used here):

```
private static void MyMethod(Expression<Func<Model, bool>> parameters) {
    // body is "p.Age != 23"
    var current = parameters.Body;            
    var binary = current as BinaryExpression;
    if (binary == null)
        throw new Exception("Invalid expression");
    // left is "p.Age"
    var left = binary.Left as MemberExpression;
    // right is "23" (constant)
    var right = binary.Right as ConstantExpression;
    if (left != null && right != null) {
        // you can check if Member has Searchable attribute here
        var propertyName = left.Member.Name; // "Age"
        var op = binary.NodeType == ExpressionType.NotEqual ? "!=" : binary.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal ? "=" : "etc..."; // "!="
        var value = right.Value; // 23
    }
}
```

Usage is as expected:

```
MyMethod(p => p.Age != 23);
MyMethod(p => p.Name == "Titan");
```

Comment: Thats great. very helpful. But i want to use this `MyMethod(Expression<Func<Model, IEnumerable<bool>>> parameters)` instead so that i can have `MyMethod(p => new[] {p.Name == "Argent", p.Age == 21})`. Then i will use your method to parse each of the array elements. How do i access each boolean expression from parameter.Body

Comment: I figured out that i could cast as NewArrayExpression to achieve that ` var expressions = parameters.Body as NewArrayExpression;` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Model, bool>> where = p => (p.Age != 23 && p.Name == "Titan");
var result = Models.Where(where);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I want call `MyMethod` and pass a number of conditional expressions. only that this time i want to have access to the lhs, operator and rhs of each conditional expression